# Validating form after error has been shown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where username and password are entered. If they are left blank an error is shown, however when one of the input box is filled in and the submit button is clicked the error that's there doesn't go away.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

      function chck() {
      var valid = true;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password_box').value;
    var user = document.getElementById('username_box').value;
            if (user == '') {
        document.getElementById('password-error').innerHTML = "* Please enter username to proceed...";
        document.getElementById('username_box').style.borderColor = "#DC3D24";
            document.getElementById('username_box').style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
        valid = false;
    }
    if (pass == '') {
        document.getElementById('user-error').innerHTML = "* Please enter password to proceed...";
        document.getElementById('password_box').style.borderColor = "#DC3D24";
            document.getElementById('password_box').style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
       valid = false;
    }else{
                   valid = true;
        }
                return valid;
    }

      </script>
</head>
<body>
      <form action="checkup.php" method="post" name="checkup">
      <div class="login-box">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username goes here.." id="username_box" class="box" name="username">
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password goes here.." id="password_box" class="box" name="password">          <BR>
           <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit_button" value="LogMeIn" onClick="return chck()">
           <input type="button" class="button" id="clear_button" value="Clear">
      </div>
      </form>        <BR>
      <center>
      <div class="error-area" id="message">
        <p id="password-error">
      </p>
      <p id="user-error">
      </p>

      </div>
      </center>
```

Only if I fill in both boxes, then the error goes away. I want to hide the error as soon as one of the boxes is filled in with text. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML5......just add **required** attribute and to clear values use **reset input**

```
<form action="checkup.php" method="post" name="checkup">
  <div class="login-box">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username goes here.." id="username_box" class="box" name="username" required title="* Please enter username to proceed...">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password goes here.." id="password_box" class="box" name="password" required title="* Please enter password to proceed...">          <BR>
       <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit_button" value="LogMeIn" onClick="return chck()">
       <input type="reset"  value="Clear">
  </div>
  </form>
```

or if you want to achieve this with the existing code try using **onfocus event** to clear the error message. Hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

You could run `chck()` on the `"keypress"` event for your "username_box" and "password_box" elements.

Like so:

```
document. getElementById("username_box").addEventListener("keypress", function () {
  chck();
}, true);
```

but update `chck` slightly to be:

```
function chck() {
  var valid = true;
  var pass = document.getElementById('password_box').value;
  document.getElementById('password-error').innerHTML = "";
  var user = document.getElementById('username_box').value;
  document.getElementById('user-error').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('password_box').setAttribute("style", "");
  document.getElementById('username_box').setAttribute("style", "");
  if (user == '') {
    document.getElementById('password-error').innerHTML = "* Please enter username to proceed...";
    document.getElementById('username_box').style.borderColor = "#DC3D24";
    document.getElementById('username_box').style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
    valid = false;
  }
  if (pass == '') {
    document.getElementById('user-error').innerHTML = "* Please enter password to proceed...";
    document.getElementById('password_box').style.borderColor = "#DC3D24";
    document.getElementById('password_box').style.backgroundColor = "maroon";
    valid = false;
  }
  else{
    valid = true;
  }
  return valid;
}
```